# High BigQuery bill with queries that don't process more than a few GB?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm currently having an issue with BigQuery where the billing is showing that I'm processing terabytes of data but when I look at the `jobs.list` endpoint, the queries are only around a GB.

What could be causing my bill to be so high when I'm really not processing that much data? My billing tier is 1 for everything as well.

Comment: how about storage? prorated $20 per 1TB per month? what other cloud services you are using? and btw - what is that high bill? what the order of number?

Comment: Firebase and BigQuery are about it and cloud storage. The bill is currently $43.77

Comment: can storage be an answer?

Comment: Is there a way I can see how much data is stored in bigquery?

Comment: you can use - SELECT SUM(size_bytes) AS dataset_size_bytes FROM \`project.dataset.__TABLES__` - run it against all datasets in your project. if you have too many to run manually one-by-one - just script it with your preferred scripting language/tool or script out sql as a unions (tere are tons of ways to do so)

Comment: It's looking like these tables are just a couple kilobytes to megabytes so it's definitely not from BigQuery storage.

Comment: if you feel you are over-billed  - you might want to contact google support than

Comment: related: https://medium.com/google-cloud/visualize-gcp-billing-using-bigquery-and-data-studio-d3e695f90c08

Comment: If you're absolutely sure it's not storage or queries, you may want to look at how you're populating the data in BQ. Are you doing any streaming inserts? Any DML? Those are really the only things you should be seeing BQ charges for with that small amount of data. Also, the first TB of processing is free now, so as @MikhailBerlyant mentioned, you may want to contact support.